# Php, how to open a small message/form window (not a new browser window)

Tags: javascript, window, modal-dialog

So , I am creating a forum using php,

Now there's a report button on every post, where any member can report a specific post.

When he clicks this button, I want him to stay on the same page, but open a small window containing a form:

Reason for report: (text box)

(buttons): Send report, Cancel

Now, I have looked around and googled it, but I don't seem to insert the right keywords to find it, So I saw it's best way to start a new question :( , cuz also most suggest opening a new window (like a new browser window), but it's not what I'm looking for

thank you very much for your help in advance :)

Note: I prefer not to use javascript, but if it's only doable through javascript, then no problem :)

shady

Comment: have a look at modal windows. You may find something with that. Without more elaboration on your question i cant provide any more info, although on first sights it looks more like a javascript operation

Comment: seems like it's what I need :) , thanks, looking it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best way to do that is using a jQuery popup function or use a JavaScript function to this, here is some example for you http://forum.jquery.com/topic/a-very-simple-popup-box-div

Comment: :) thanks for the example @itsme , You think the code is good in this exampl?, as I have no experience in jQuery, I think i will copy the code and just adjust it what I need :)

Comment: There is a lot of examples online I just post you one of it, try to google jquery div popup sample, you'll get alot results, good luck :)

Comment: Hey m8 :), well , the thing is I finished the website, and this forum is my last step :-), it's the reason why I don't want to get into Javascript programming right now, also cuz have to publish the website asap. Is there a way to contact you? for very simple 2 questions, or do you prefer that I post these questions here? :), (simply because they are not mainly related to especificly my question)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for an easy javascript way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you are still after a new window however you just need to give it the right arguments so it doesnt have status bar etc.  in Javascript call

```
window.open(theURL,winName,features);
```

You need to give it the right features.

Comment: What about a javascript modal dialog?

Comment: Yeah I mean theres plenty of ways to cerate modal dialogs, for example using divs etc as part of the same page.  From my understanding though (I may have misunderstood) they were after the new window but without title bar, tabs, status bar scroll bars etc which quite a lot of websites use for example for pop out chat services etc.

Comment: well , what you mean is , I can create a normal php page, which contains the report form, and simply show it as a pop up, through the window.open fuction. To be honest I have no idea how it would look, but ofcourse I can set the new window's width/heigh, positioning... etc, have I understood currectly?

Comment: Yes but more importantly you can pass a feature set, this tells it what in the window should be displayed, i.e status bar, scroll bars etc.  However you can create popups in the current html page using javascript and a div if thats what you want, which is essentially what things like the jQuery UI Dialog does.

Comment: yeah , seems that a jQuery dialog box is what I prefer :), though thanks alot for your help m8 :)